# Is there a script to determine linux user name?

Tags: linux, find, installation

I am looking for some code to get the linux username..  I have come across code to get current username but what I need to get is the username that was used when installing linux..

For example, if im logged in as root user, how can i get the initial username that was used when installing ubuntu?

Better still, Is there a variable that I can put in my script that will search & store install username..

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf] or [su].  Also, what do you mean by "the username that was used when installing ubuntu". When you are installing, there is no user.  The root user, and maybe one other non-system account, is/are created during postinstall.  Asking for the "username that was used when installing ubuntu" is not a meaningful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use fact, that default uid and gid for first created user is 1000:

```
grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd|cut -f1 -d':'
```

but keep in mind:

1. when default user was deleted, you get empty string
2. if it running on non standard configuration, uid, and gid may be different
3. this is not good practise (see next point)
4. you ate not considering multi-seat configurations, when station have many users, you should provide user config file, where user can put usernames he wants to processed or do it from command line

Comment: Brilliant, that worked a treat..  Is there any way to make that a variable in a script without having to run a script to determine this first?  for example, could I use something like: `username=$(grep 1000:1000: /etc/passwd|cut -f1 -d':')`

Comment: Please ignore last question, Tested & working, thank you for your help Szpadel